# Power Apps Component

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-collection, powerapps-modeldriven

I have started working on components in Power App, and noticed that when you want to create the Component Library I have a (preview) next to it. Also, when I create a component and I tab over to screens screen, the only screen usable is for mobile layout. When I try to import a new screen, the only option for the new screen is for mobile only.

So my questions are:

1. Why do I have preview next to the component library if components are readily available for both canvas and model-driven apps?!
2. Why can I only see the screen that is for mobile when making a component inside Component Library?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So my questions are:

*Why do I have preview next to the component library if components are readily available for both canvas and model-driven apps?!*

Becuase they are not yet General Availablity i.e Microsoft says not yet completely ready for Production deployment but could be used/tested in dev/test instances

*Why can I only see the screen that is for mobile when making a component inside Component Library?*

I suspect this is only available for Mobile, but you can change the screen mode to landscape or so on.

Comment: There is no more preview, as per Microsoft, components are generally available
https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/announcing-the-general-availability-of-canvas-components-and-component-libraries/

The other question is still not clear to me, I know we can change it to landscape, but why is there only an option for mobile layout?